# Getting numbers from a separated list

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that looks like this

```
String read = "1130:5813|1293:5803|1300:5755|1187:5731|"
```

As you can see there are 4 pair of integer values.

I want to add there values into the list something like this

```
a = 1130
b = 5813

groupIt pair = new groupIt(a,b);
List<groupIt> group  = new ArrayList<groupIt>();
group.add(pair);
```

How can I do this for the 4 pair of String.

Can `Pattern.compile()` be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why won't you use

```
String[] tokens = read.split("\\|");
for (String token : tokens) {
   String[] params = token.split(":");
   Integer a = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
   Integer b = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);

   // ...

}
```

Comment: params should be a String[]. And you might have to escape the |, as split accepts a regexp.

Comment: @gpeche You are absolutely right. I've just amended my response.

Comment: Yes i can do that too. Thanks for the help.. it works.Actually i was trying with patterns.. But this works.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at google guava and its `Splitter` - it is much more likely to do what you expect from a split-method and is fast. Plus, I love google and their fluent interfaces... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for good measure, here is your regex:

```
public class RegexClass {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}):(\\d{4})\\|");

    public void parse() {
        String text = "1130:5813|1293:5803|1300:5755|1187:5731|";
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
           one = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
           two = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

           // Do something with them here
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do think that Michael is correct: his solution is better!

Good luck...